# CXF Double signatures while using AsymmetricBindingHandler

Tags: java, cxf

WSDL: http://pastebin.com/Xx82fmGX
Response: http://pastebin.com/KbuMrfn4

In the given response signatures appear double or even triple.

I debugged the source code of CXF 2.7.13.

The getSignedParts method in AbstractBinding is called twice.
The first call is done in the doEncryptBeforeSign method at line 262.
Second call is done in the doSignature at line 506, called by doEncryptBeforeSign method at line 301.

Anyone an idea what I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already fixed in CXF: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6473

Colm.